# not to create an object with new Constructor

Tags: javascript

Is there an option to not create an object with particular condition within constructor, e.g.

```
function Monster(name, hp) {
    if (hp < 1) {
       delete this;
    }
    else {
           this.name = name;
    }
}
var theMonster = new Monster("Sulley", -5); // undefined
```

Comment: Why don´t you move your condition outside of your `Monster` function? You cannot use `theMonster` anyway if you don´t want it to be an object. You could add `this.isMonster = (hp >= 1);` to your `Monster` function.

Comment: is throwing an exception an option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're supposed to do is throw an exception.

```
function Monster(name, hp) {
    if (hp < 1) {
        throw "health points cannot be less than 1";
    }
    this.hp = hp;
    this.name = name;
}

var m = new Monster("Not a good monster", 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

A function called as a constructor (with the `new` operator) will always return an instance *unless* it explicitly returns an object. You can therefore return an empty object, and use the `instanceof` operator to check what came back:

```
function Monster(name, hp) {
    if (hp < 1) {
       return {};
    }
    else {
       this.name = name;
    }
}
var theMonster = new Monster("Sulley", -5);

console.log(theMonster instanceof Monster); // false
```

This behaviour is explained in the spec ([13.2.2](http://es5.github.com/#x13.2.2)):

> 8. Let *result* be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal property of F, providing obj as the this value and providing the argument list passed into [[Construct]] as *args*.
>
> 9. **If Type(result) is Object then return result**.
>
> 10. Return obj.

However, as others have pointed out, whether you should actually do this is questionable.

Comment: It is a programming error to create a Monster with negative health, why would you go out of your way to make it silent and undiscoverable until later with completely unrelated error messages. Throwing an exception is the only thing to do.

Comment: @Esailija - I didn't say I agreed with the approach, I just answered the question ("Is there an option to not create an object with particular condition within constructor?"). I have added a note to say that you probably shouldn't do this.

Comment: It's not an error if the monster is undead... if you know what I mean ;)

Comment: I agree an exception would be better, but +1 for the spec anyways

Answer (score 1):

It does not make sense, you are trying to stop construction of an object during its construction phase. The better way would be to use something suggested by  @Amberlamps or use something like factory pattern to create objects.